# it is posible to do " if error go to sub "

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write code that goes to a specific path and imports data from it,
then goes to another path and do the same.

I need that if path num 1 does not exist, it will jump direct to path num 2.

I wrote a sub for each path. there is a way to do something like:

```
if error goto sub ___  ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can do something like

```
On Error Goto error_sub1
```

and at the bottom of your function, write

```
error_sub1:
'ToDo - put your calling code here.
```

Elsewhere in you function you can switch the error handler to a different label:

```
On Error Goto error_sub2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub testSO()

On Error GoTo err
I=5/0

Exit Sub
err:
<your sub procedure here>

End Sub
```

Remember to include Exit Sub or else it will still run even without error!

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to avoid the error in the first place and check whether the file exists before attempting to open it?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sFile1 As String
    Dim sFile2 As String
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    sFile1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\MyFile1.xls"
    sFile2 = "C:\Users\Desktop\MyFile2.xls"

    If FileExists(sFile1) Then
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(sFile1)
    ElseIf FileExists(sFile2) Then
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(sFile2)
    Else
        Err.Raise 513, , "File Not Found."
    End If

    wrkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "Opened this file."

    On Error GoTo 0

Fast_Exit:
'Any tidying up that needs doing.

Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, _
        "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number)
    Err.Clear
    Resume Fast_Exit

End Sub

Public Function FileExists(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExists = oFSO.FileExists(FileName)
End Function
```